# Remove all URL parameters in Paw

Tags: paw-app

I feel like I'm missing something basic, but I've googled and explored all around the interface and I can't find out how to remove multiple URL parameters at once without using the "Undo" or removing the request in its entirety. Basically I have requests with around 50 or more url parameters, and since Paw doesn't show these in the URL field, the only way I can see to remove them is being using the little minus symbol by each one, but this is quite tedious when you have lots. How do I remove multiple ones at once?

Comment: There is no code, I was told by the Paw website to report the problem here, it's a GUI application, no code involved.

Comment: Hey Danny! Sorry for the slow response, I had missed this message. Unfortunately, there's no way to batch delete the URL params. Clearly, something we should be adding at some point, as I can perfectly see how tedious it is when there are many params to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but this has been irritating me for a while now as well. Would love to see a batch delete action added for url params, but for now I create a version of the request with no params, then duplicate it when I need to start with a clean request. Definitely can clutter up the request list, but they could be thrown into a subfolder or some such and duplicated there if a lot of them might be needed. Either way, it's faster than always having to manually remove params - in my case just 15 or so but that's still an aggravation.